# Keras LSTM parameters misleading with documentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I implemented an `LSTM` with `Keras`, but I have doubts about the parameters requested. I only used two parameters: `units` and `input_shape`. In the official documentation (https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm), the parameter `input_shape` isn't mentioned and if I use also the `activation` parameter, I got an error saying that I can't use the parameter `activation`.

I installed `Keras 2.3.0` and `Tensorflow 2.1.0` and `LSTM` layer is imported from `tensorflow.keras.layers`.

What is the problem? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you provide your code and the error logs please?

Comment: @Thomas Schillaci Ehm, sorry, now it works. Maybe I used a cached version of the code.